# Compilation Error: Requires Explicit Package Name

Tags: perl, file, file-io, compiler-errors

I am just starting out with Perl and I am writing a program that reads a file and puts the morse code from that file into plain text in another file. I am getting this error and I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Error I am receiving:

```
Jessicas-MacBook-Pro:Documents jessica$ perl -w Morse_to_Text.pl <Morse3.rtf> MorseTest.txt
Global symbol "$message" requires explicit package name at Morse_to_Text.pl line 20.
Global symbol "$message" requires explicit package name at Morse_to_Text.pl line 26.
Global symbol "$message" requires explicit package name at Morse_to_Text.pl line 26.
Global symbol "$message" requires explicit package name at Morse_to_Text.pl line 27.
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

 use 5.010;
 use strict;
 use warnings;


my %morsecode=(
".-" =>"A", "-..." => "B", "-.-." => "C", "-.." => "D", "." => "E",
"..-." => "F", "--." => "G", "...." => "H", ".." => "I", ".---" => "J",
"-.-" => "K", ".-.." => "L", "--" => "M", "-." => "N", "---" => "O", 
".--." => "P", "--.-" => "Q", ".-." => "R", "..." => "S", "-" => "T",
"..-" => "U", "...-" => "V", ".--" => "W", "-..-" => "X", "-.--" => "Y",
"--.." => "Z", "-----" => "0", ".----" => "1", "..---" => "2", "...--" => "3",
"....-" => "4", "....." => "5", "-...." => "6", "--..." => "7", "---.." => "8",
"----." => "9", ".-.-.-" => ".", "--..--" => ",", "..--.." => "?", ".----." => "'",
"-....-" => "-", ".-..-." => '"', ".--.-." => "@", "-...-" => "=", "!" => " "
);


while (<>) {
    chomp;
    foreach my $char ( split ' ' ) {

        $message = $morsecode{$char} + $message;
        print $message;
    };
}
```

Comment: Note that `.` is the string concatenation operator. [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: If you want to split a string into chars, you want `split //`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the . is the string concatenation. I could not find it in the documentation you provided

Comment: "a" + "b" gives zero. "a" . "b" gives "ab". Mentioned under "Additive Operators".

Comment: You don't need `-w` if you use `use warnings;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use strict, so you should declare the global variable $message first. But as ikegami said in comment, use strict and warnings are one of the best practices when writing perl code. The pragmas catch many errors sooner that they would be caught otherwise, which makes it easier to find the root causes of the errors (just like the error you provide). The root cause might be the need for an error or validation check, and that can happen regardless or programmer skill.

I think what you want is the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

 use 5.010;
 use strict;
 use warnings;


my %morsecode=(
".-" =>"A", "-..." => "B", "-.-." => "C", "-.." => "D", "." => "E",
"..-." => "F", "--." => "G", "...." => "H", ".." => "I", ".---" => "J",
"-.-" => "K", ".-.." => "L", "--" => "M", "-." => "N", "---" => "O", 
".--." => "P", "--.-" => "Q", ".-." => "R", "..." => "S", "-" => "T",
"..-" => "U", "...-" => "V", ".--" => "W", "-..-" => "X", "-.--" => "Y",
"--.." => "Z", "-----" => "0", ".----" => "1", "..---" => "2", "...--" => "3",
"....-" => "4", "....." => "5", "-...." => "6", "--..." => "7", "---.." => "8",
"----." => "9", ".-.-.-" => ".", "--..--" => ",", "..--.." => "?", ".----." => "'",
"-....-" => "-", ".-..-." => '"', ".--.-." => "@", "-...-" => "=", "!" => " "
);

my $message;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    foreach my $char ( split ' ' ) {
        $message = $message.$morsecode{$char};
    };
}

print $message."\n";
```

Comment: I purposefully didn't write out the solution for him since he's obviously trying to learn.

Comment: I don't even think you did it right. Combining the output of all lines of input into one line of output doesn't seem right.

Comment: Also, you falsely imply declaring `$message` is something he should only do when strict. And that's not mentioning that you make it sound like not using strict in a program is sometimes acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit this answer. The code is just for a reference. He can modify based on it if he doesn't want to put the result into one line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not using the concatenate method right at all haha.

Answer (score 1):

It means you didn't declare `$message` using `my $message;` where appropriate.

---

You might benefit from running your script using

```
perl -Mdiagnostics script.pl
```

It'll explain many warnings/errors.